# Can't Install netflix-desktop in Debian....Aptitude Has Unmet/Broken Dependencies

Tags: debian, package-management, apt, aptitude, dependencies

I'm trying to install the netflix-desktop package in Debian 'jessie'. I was able to get this to work on my laptop running Debian 'wheezy' a few months ago, but on my desktop I keep running into [these errors](https://gist.github.com/Cheeser12/5938002) when I run:

```
aptitude install netflix-desktop
```

I already added the i386 architecture and tried running `apt-get install -f` and `aptitude install -f` to try and fix any broken packages. It's worth noting that it's not just the 'netflix-desktop' package that does this: other packages (which are also 'netflix-desktop' dependencies) like 'ia32-libs' give similar messages about broken dependencies.

So I'm a little stumped. If anybody has any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try following the debugging tips in http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/121180/4671. Expressly written for this type of question. See my answer for quite precise debugging directions. If you have questions, ping me.

Comment: Slightly more generally, see http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3026/4671

Answer (score 0):

did you add ppa ? You will have to add PPA (Personal Packages Archives) in order to [install Netflix on Linux](http://namhuy.net/1867/how-to-install-netflix-on-ubuntu-linux-mint-and-fedora.html).

```
$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
```